# Display Date Difference in Formatted readable style

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have to show the difference of two dates in format like "1 year 3 Months" like wise. I have binded a model to the view and it is returning the date. How can get the date difference and show it in the view like above ? should i use jquery or razor syntax ? what will be the best method.(Deducting date is a fixed one)

here's my view code:

```
<td>
    <div>  
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hire_date) 
    </div> 
</td>
```

Comment: this method is more harder i just modified the model before passing it ti view it is more easier than this thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the calculation in Service layer and modified the model before passing it to view

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of libraries will might help with that type of formatting.

- [Noda Time - Server Side](http://nodatime.org/)
- [MomentJs - Client Side](http://momentjs.com/)
- [Humanizer - Server Side - From @schaefea answer](http://humanizr.net/)

Alternatively you can roll your own.

As you are only using it for display, I would stick with the Razor Syntax on the server side.
If however you need to use the date on the client side for other things and if you already using JQuery then it might be worthwhile using something like MomentJs.
Like all great answers to software questions:- It depends :)

Comment: I like to write a small javascript code , instead of using libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Humanizer is a library that is really useful for this kind of task: https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer#humanize-datetime

Comment: +1 great find.  I'll add that to my list of useful librares :)

Comment: I can't take any credit, I didn't write the library. Thanks for giving me the upvote and credit in your comment.